# Is it possible to get user information that failed to log in (authentication) in SpringSecurity unsuccessfulAuthentication Method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken;

        try {
            LoginDto loginInfo = objectMapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginDto.class);
            authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginInfo.getUserEmail(), loginInfo.getPassword());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null);
        }
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) {
        SecurityUserDetails userDetails = (SecurityUserDetails) authResult.getPrincipal();
        String jwtRefreshToken = jwtProvider.generateRefreshToken();
        //jwtProvider.setRefreshToken(userDetails, jwtRefreshToken);

        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + jwtProvider.generateToken(userDetails));
        //response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtProvider.generateRefreshTokenCookie(jwtRefreshToken).toString());
        //response.addHeader("userEmail", userDetails.getUser().getUserEmail());


        securityService.createSecurityLog(SecurityLogAction.login(userDetails));
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {

        SecurityUserDetails userDetails = (SecurityUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        // -> Just Null

        log.info(userDetails.getUsername());

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        Response loginFail = Response.builder()
                .code(SecurityErrorCode.LOGIN_FAIL.getErrorCode())
                .result(SecurityErrorCode.LOGIN_FAIL.getErrorMessage())
                .build();
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginFail));
        response.getWriter().flush();
        response.getWriter().close();

    }
}
```

Here is my code.

Authentication such as login success or failure works without problems.

Here, I would like to add logic that logs or restricts logins based on user information when login fails.

However, after authentication fails, the information of the user who attempted authentication is no longer accessible.

Is there a way to access the information of the user who tried to log in in the unsuccessfulAuthentication method, which is called when authentication fails?

Comment: As it is unsuccesful there will be nothing, obviously, in the `SecurityContext` as that will only provide/contain valid authentications. Also you shouldn't be writing a response in the `unsuccesfulAuthentication` method as that will break other filters in the chain. What you should implement is an event listener (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/events.html) to handle failures. That event for the failure will contain the needed information.

Comment: @dur When I tried a similar method, I confirmed that it worked. I haven't implemented it 100%, but I think it's probably another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

@M. Deinum

Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem. (I can't upvote because you commented)

I'm releasing the code that I solved with the solution you provided.

// Add Code

[SecurityConfig.java] (Where SecurityFilterChain etc. are implemented)

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    }
```

// Make File

[AuthenticationEvents.java]

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AuthenticationEvents {

    @EventListener
    public void handleAuthenticationSuccessEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();
        log.info("Successful authentication result: {}", authentication.getPrincipal());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleAuthenticationFailureEvent(AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent event) {
        Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();

        String userEmail = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        log.warn("Unsuccessful authentication result: {}", userEmail);
    }
}
```